# Find ellipse center from 3 points (in 3D)

Tags: conic-sections, 3d

I have following problem:

a camera detects 3 points with 3D coordinates, and I know all those points are on a ellipse. Additionally I know length of the major and minor axis of the ellipse. Is it possible from that information to calculate the center of the ellipse? I am kind of lost how to do that with ellipses.

Comment: Could you do it with three points with 2D coordinates and the major and minor axes?

Comment: I don't know how, even in 2D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you can identify the plane containing the three points.  The center will lie in that plane.  You can rotate to make it a $2d$ problem if needed.  Alternatively you can in most cases project it onto the $xy$ plane.

Next, you can try to use the reflective properties of an ellipse.  If $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the foci, and the three points are $P_1$, $P_2$, and $P_3$, then $d(P_i, F_1) + d(P_i, F_2)$ is a constant, which you can find from the major and minor axes.  That gives you three equations.

**Edited to add**
Since you have the major and minor axes you can compute how far apart the foci are.  That gives you another condition, which should be enough to solve.

Comment: It seems to me that your procedure gives you three equations in four unknowns (the coordinates of $F_1$ and $F_2$ in the 2D plane), and so you still wouldn't be able to solve.  Specifically, the distance $d(P_i, F_1) + d(P_i, F_2)$ is equal to the major axis of the ellipse;  this procedure doesn't use the information we have about the minor axis.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Good catch, thanks.  We also know the distance between the foci, which gives another equation.  Edited to add.

Answer (score 2):

Using the three given points we can identify the plane on which the three points lie.

Create an $x'y'$ coordinate system for that plane with its origin at any point on the plane and with an arbitrary orientation.  The only requirement is that both the $x'$ and $y'$ axes lie on the plane.

Next, find the $x'y'$ coordinates of the three given points, let these be $(x_1, y_1), (x_2, y_2), (x_3, y_3)$.  In addition, we know $a$ and $b$, the semi-major and semi-minor axes lengths.

The equation of the ellipse in the plane is

$ (r - C)^T Q (r - C) = 1 $

where $r = [x, y]^T$ and $C$ is the center of the ellipse, and,

$Q = \begin{bmatrix} \dfrac{\cos^2 \theta}{a^2} + \dfrac{\sin^2 \theta}{b^2} && \sin \theta \cos \theta (\dfrac{1}{a^2} - \dfrac{1}{b^2}) \\ \sin \theta \cos \theta (\dfrac{1}{a^2} - \dfrac{1}{b^2}) && \dfrac{\cos^2 \theta}{b^2} + \dfrac{\sin^2 \theta}{a^2} \end{bmatrix} $

where $\theta$ is the angle that the major axis makes with the positive $x'$ axis.

Now plugging in the three points in the ellipse equation results in three equations in three unknowns which are the two coordinates of the center and the angle $\theta$.

These three equations can be solved using an iterative method like the Newton-Raphson multivariate method, which is very fast and efficient.

Finally, once we have $C$, the three-dimensional coordinates of the center can be computed.